# What is the name of a fallacy for thinking something is easy for others because it is easy for you?

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't remember where I was reading this, but whoever posted on the page said something along the lines of there being a fallacy that means:

> believing a task to be easy for others because it is easy for you

I looked it up afterwards and found other references to it, so I believe it is a real fallacy and not just something that person made up. This has been stuck in my head for weeks so any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's easy for you to say!

Comment: I'm confused. You say you looked it up and that confirmed it's a real fallacy, but you're still asking here. Did you just forget the label? What was it you looked for? Can you do that again?

Comment: I checked logical fallacies for one that might be this specific.  There isn't, but there is a general one called "relativist fallacy", which is a logical conclusion that something is true because it is true for you (or someone you know).  Example: "I lost my first tooth at age 6, so that's when kids lose their first tooth."

Comment: Its probably a [cognitive bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases), rather than a fallacy.

Comment: arrogant narcissism

Comment: Doesn't this belong on http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ ? Could someone flag for migration?

Comment: Yep, it was a cognitive bias, not a fallacy. No wonder I couldn't find it lol.

Comment: And @Area51DetectiveFiction, as much as I love putting questions in their proper exchanges, I was just looking for a name to the definition, not asking a question on how the bias works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is part of ***Dunning-Kruger effect***.

> ... highly skilled individuals tend to underestimate their relative competence, erroneously assuming that tasks which are easy for them are also easy for others.
>
> [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)